# Multiple pdf files with multiple plots in each in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, pdf

I realize my code is probably inelegant but it's what I got.

I am working with a very large data set that is eventually pared down to multiple data frames. I am trying to write it in a way that is useable for multiple data sets of different sizes so you can simply load in the original data and go. I'm also working within a niche package for spatial analysis.

Ok, so for the function

`plot_dist(census=df ensemble = vector of 1 or 2 variables in data frame)`

I want to plot for each column singly in the data frame and then also each column plotted against all the other columns.

I can do this with the plots generating in R

```
n <- c(1:length(list_of_variables)-1) 
for (j in 1:length(list_of_dfs)) {
  for (k in 1:length(list_of_variables)) {
      plot_dist(census = list_of_dfs[[j]], ensemble = list_of_variables[k])
      for (m in 1:length(n)) {
        if (is.na(list_of_variables[k+n[m]]))next
        plot_dist(list_of_dfs[[j]], ensemble = c(list_of_variables[k], list_of_variables[k+n[m]]))
      }}}
```

This creates the expected plots individually in R

When I try

```
n <- c(1:length(list_of_variables)-1)
#plot distribution. This one works for both plot types. Needs PDF
for (j in 1:length(list_of_dfs)) {
  for (k in 1:length(list_of_variables)) {
    for (i in 1:length(data_files)) {
      pdf(file = paste("dist_plots_", data_files[i], ".pdf", sep = ""),
        onefile = TRUE)
      plot_dist(census = list_of_dfs[[j]], ensemble = ensemble_list[k])
      for (m in 1:length(n)) {
      if (is.na(ensemble_list[k+n[m]]))next
      plot_dist(list_of_dfs[[j]], ensemble = c(list_of_variables[k], list_of_variables[k+n[m]]))
    dev.off()
       }}}}
```

I get pdfs with only the last plot created

EDIT

With these minor changes I now get individual pdf files that contain all the plots from each df and the files wont open until I exit R

```
#Gives 3 identical pdfs with all the plots in each
# Can't open PDFs until I restart R
for (i in 1:length(data_files)) {
pdf(file = paste( data_files[i], "dist_plots", ".pdf", sep = "_"))
for (j in 1:length(list_of_dfs)) {
  for (k in 1:length(list_of_variables)) {
      plot_dist(census = list_of_dfs[[j]], ensemble = list_of_variables[k], radius = rad, bin_num = 100, plot_zoom = T)
      for (m in 1:length(n)) {
      if (is.na(list_of_variables[k+n[m]]))next
      plot_dist(census_data_list_plot[[j]], ensemble = c(list_of_variables[k], list_of_variables[k+n[m]]), radius = rad, plot_zoom = T )
         }}}}
dev.off()
```